# How to make inference based on a box-plot?

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics, boxplot

1) Write a comment about age comparing the box-plots at two levels of treatment compliance levels.

2) What are the interquartile ranges of BMI for comparing these two levels of treatment compliance levels?

3) From Age and BMI which variable is more related to treatment compliance levels and why?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. You might want to take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info. Following these guidelines is likely to lead to more useful answers to your question.

Comment: *"From Age and BMI which variable is more related to treatment compliance levels and why?"* This seems like a question for some kind of course, exam or study. I consider this a nasty/tricky question (ie. badly designed because the point that should come across, I guess something about boxplots, interferes with the background of this matter 'BMI vs age')........

Comment: ....... It would be very much overinterpreting the experiment to make any conclusion just on these two boxplots alone. What we would need (instead) is a scatter plot of BMI vs age (and it is very common for BMI to increase with age) and make the comparison between compliance level by using different colour or some other difference between the points.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus , yes, correct. But, the question was formed like this. I have tried to solve it first but can't find any logical way to solve it. Could you help to figure it out from the current question?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a lot like a question for a course, exam or study. If this is the case then you should mention this because in that case the answer can be tailored with respect to the educational/didactical **goal** of the question/problem.

Anyway, here is some (incomplete) guidance:

...

We can find that the boxplot from this particular problem relates to research on hypertension. More specifically: [Hossain, A., Mithila, O. Sleep duration and treatment compliance: a population-based cross-sectional study of hypertensive patients in Bangladesh. *BMC Res Notes* **9**, 271 (2016).](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13104-016-2075-6)

The boxplot is used to *describe* the data from a questionnaire filled in by 101 participants in the study (out of 512 initial participants, from which 123 had hypertension and, from those 101 participated to fill in the questionnaire).

It is very nice that the study comes along with the original data, so we can make the following scatter plot age and BMI, where we color the points differently based on the compliance (the compliance was based on answers in the questionnaire).

[image: boxplots along with scatter plot of data]

---

In the particular study the researchers performed a logistic regression and found out that the coefficient for BMI is significant, but not the coefficient for age.

To me it seems that this questions is meant to stimulate you to learn (by experience/exploration) how to observe patterns based on boxplots. *Sidenote: It is a bit mixed however. On the one hand the question 2 is asking for a very plain/straightforward/direct question 'what is the interquartile range?' which means that you just look up the definition of the [IQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) and apply it to the graph/plot (it is a bit tricky because the drawing of the boxes, and especially the whiskers, in box-plots may be done according to different definitions). On the other hand the questions 1 and 3 are more asking about interpretation of the plot.*

I would consider this question (the parts 1 and 3) a bit difficult to answer and it depends on the *meaning* of the tutor/questioner how you should answer this question. There are several (subtle) concepts mixed together.

- In the regression the coefficient for bmi is significant, and the coefficient for age is not. But,

  - This doesn't mean that the compliance doesn't correlate with age. This is because age correlates with bmi. In the boxplots you see that for both cases age and bmi the non compliance correlates with higher bmi *and also* with higher age.
  - In a regression the age is not significant, but that doesn't mean there is not an effect of age. A positive effect of age was found, but it is only not considered significant (it is not surpassing a level such that we can say this effect is unlikely/remarkable and should be considered an anomaly)
- It is a nuanced case. Maybe the professor/tutor wants you to see that **the boxes are very close to each other (they overlap)**. This means that there is not much difference between the two groups. However, even though the two boxes are much the same **this doesn't mean that there isn't a tiny difference**. This difference can be very accurately measured if you have a sufficiently large sample size. That is what is happening here (This is also why it is difficult to conclude anything, about signficance, from the boxplot alone. The regression, based on computation, is providing an additional and more quantitative support to our initial qualitative assessment).

---

If you like to replicate all of this then download the data and follow:

```r
### data
data <- read.csv("~/datacompliance.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")

#converting the category for duration
data$Durationofhypertension <- as.factor(c(1,3,1,2,2,3,3)[data$Durationofhypertension])



### plotting
par(mar = c(3,3,1,1), mgp = c(1.5,0.5,0))
layout(matrix(c(2,1,4,3),2), widths = c(2,1), heights= c(1,2))

plot(data$Age,data$BMI, 
     col=c(1,1)[data$FinalCompliance], 
      bg=c(2,0)[data$FinalCompliance],
     pch = 21,
     xlab = "age", ylab = "bmi")

legend(25,38,c("no compliance", "compliance"),
       col=1, pt.bg=c(2,0), pch=21, cex=0.7)

### curve for BMI vs age
mod <- lm(data$BMI ~ data$Age)
t <- c(1:100)
lines(t,t*mod$coefficients[2]+mod$coefficients[1], lty = 2)

### boxplots
boxplot(data$Age ~ data$FinalCompliance, col=c(2,0)[data$compliancewithmedicine], horizontal=TRUE )
boxplot(data$BMI ~ data$FinalCompliance, col=c(2,0)[data$compliancewithmedicine])


### replicating the model from the article
mod <- glm(FinalCompliance ~ Age + Sex + MaritalStatus + BMI + Otherproblem.1 + FamilyHistory +
             smoking +  Sleephour + Durationofhypertension + FamilyHistory,
           family=binomial(link = "logit"), data=data)
summary(mod)
```